# Display xy value on Google Chart on mouse over

Tags: google-apps-script

I have searched for an answer to this for a week. Seems like a essential simple function to have yet I cannot find a way to do this. I have a simple xy chart using two columns of data. Time vs Temperature. I would like to be able to hover over a certain point in the chart to display both its time and temperature value automatically, almost like a tool tip would. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: ploty has an online tool which has this functionality out of the box (searched for this for hours) https://chart-studio.plotly.com/create/#/ Also this tutorial shows you how to activate the functionality: https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/label-points-with-text-in-a-scatter-plot/

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of chart and its screenshot where you can see both x,y points.

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-cW1Kzz8svoOUZtLUdTU0s2dm8/view?usp=sharing)

**Code**

```
function doGet() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Url to your spreadsheet');


  var range = sh.getRange("A1:B10");
  var data=range.getValues();

  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
               .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Number")
               .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Number");
  for(var j=1; j<data.length; j++){
    dataTable.addRow([data[j][0],data[j][1]]);

  }
  dataTable.build();
   var chartBuilder = Charts.newLineChart()
       .setTitle('Data')
       .setXAxisTitle('Time (ms)')
       .setYAxisTitle('Temperatures (F)')
       .setDimensions(600, 500)
       .setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH)
       .setPointStyle(Charts.PointStyle.MEDIUM)
       .setDataTable(dataTable);

   var chart = chartBuilder.build();

  Uiapp = UiApp.createApplication()
  var mypanel=Uiapp.createVerticalPanel().add(chart);;
  return Uiapp.add(mypanel);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @user1989 for the help but when i amend your script to suit my spreadsheet, it runs without error (aside from api's being deprecated) but no chart appears. Should i see it in the sheet where my data is? Could it be a permissions issue? I am probably missing

Comment: This is working perfectly fine. There might be something wrong with data columns in your spreadsheet. I am using A1:B10 columns. Try to put your data into these columns, it will work. Look at my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xB-CRVfKabsdeE0LxuTuuT9auM36Ujw2eFj4vOMvOHY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I created a new sheet, put some simple data into A1:B10 just like your test sheet, updated the script to use the new sheet URL but still nothing. Should running it within the script editor produce something or does it have to be called elsewhere? Apologies for such newby questions.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. well I prefer to run it within the script editor with the same sheet for test, but if you want to run from a separate stand alone script from a different email account, you must have an access to that sheet.  Issue might be with authorization of script, try to authorize the script first.

Comment: I am running it in the script editor. Not using a separate Gmail account. Beats me what's wrong..

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong, but it's pretty straight forward. Try to run your code in debug mode, that's all I can say.

Comment: Thanks man. It baffles me why something so simple produces nothing. As I say, the script seems to run without error. The only debug messages I see are telling me that some of the commands have been deprecated. Here is a link to my spreadsheet hopefully giving full access. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Wr6z0WXQtmUJUc_zLkZLG-KXYlwUHvP0Q1yV9J6RkY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It appears the link above doesn't allow you to see or edit the script but the only difference to the code you posted is the sheet URL which should be identical to above.

Comment: My code is also working with your spreadhsheet. I don't understand why it doesn't work for you.